# Removing components from wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2

WSO2 API manager has 4 components

API Gateway
API Publisher
API Store
API Key Manager Server

I would like to run each of these components on separate boxes. While doing so on box  where I have API Publisher component I want to remove other 3 components from the api manager so on with other components. By this I would like to achieve that only 1 component exists at run time of each instance of wso2 api manger.

I would like to know how can we remove each of these components from wso2 api manager?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the relevant features from the product via Carbon Feature Management (Or you can add necessary features as well).

You can find more information regarding how to uninstall a particular feature [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Uninstalling+Features).
You can also find more information regarding feature management for WSO2 Carbon products [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Feature+Management).

HTH,
Lasantha

Comment: I went through the list of features installed. I don't find the components Publisher or Store or Key Manager or Gateway. There is one component API manager instead. From this looks it is not possible to remove sub components of API manager.

Answer (score 0):

Installing High Level components is supported from API Manager 1.5.0 onwards. If you want to start API Manager as one of the components, that can be achieved by starting as a server profile. You can find more information [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Running+the+Product+on+a+Preferred+Profile).